# Add combo to tinymce toolbar, choosing an option injects some text

Tags: javascript, tinymce

how to create a plug-in to add combo to toolbar? On that combo choosing an option will inject some predefined text into the editor.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE already has two possible solutions for your needs:

The `template` plugin:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/template/

The `textpattern` plugin:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/textpattern/